# Рисование на виджете канвасом

Tags: виджет, android, java

Всем привет. Я уже задавал такой вопрос, но ответа так и не получил, задаю еще раз :) Я пытаюсь нарисовать на виджете линию, круг или прямоугольник через канву, но ничего не получается....

**UPD:**
решение найдено http://dajver.blogspot.com/2012/04/canvas-android.html

Comment: @dajver, желательно всё-таки не дублировать вопросы. В прошлой теме вам был дан точно такой же, к слову, абсолютно верный, ответ.

Comment: Я понимаю, но я не понял каким образом это все потом вывести на виджет... Я этот вопрос задал.

Comment: Судя по записи у вас в блоге, вы неточно сформулировали этот вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А причем тут AppWidgetProvider? AppWidgetProvider нечто похожее на BroadcastReceiver - по сути некий сервис, который говорит "я умею показывать виджет", но он сам не рисует виджет! Это провайдер!

Чтобы нарисовать виджет надо составить кастомный класс наследующий от `View` и в его методе `onDraw()` написать то что хотите. Вам уже в прошлый раз камрады указывали на вашу ошибку.

Есличо смотрите пример реализации кастомного виджета [здесь](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/08/example-of-custom-widget-view.html)

**Update**

```
public class MySuperPuperWidgetView extends SomeExistingWidgetView
{

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas); //рисуем виджет
        //далее пишем свою хрень на канвасе
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну так я на нем же рисовать пытаюсь. Хотя я могу ошибаться, какие есть предложения?

Comment: Смотрите апдейт ответа

Comment: Спасибо, я понял что нужно так сделать, но как мне это вывести потом на виджет? Вот этого я не понимаю.

Comment: В смысле не существующий виджет? Надо взять класс виджета, наследовать от него, перегрузить его метод onDraw вызвать super.onDraw() - чтобы он нарисовал себя, а сверху потом нарисовать то что хотите.

Comment: Про не существующий вилжет я вроде бы не писал. Можно это хотя бы примерным кодом показать, я не понял как это "наследовать от него, перегрузить его метод onDraw вызвать super.onDraw() "

Comment: См. апдейт в ответе

Comment: Обновил код в вопросе, исправьте, что там не так, пожалуйста